# Assistance needed on what machine learning approach to use

Tags: classification, clustering, reinforcement-learning

I'm currently writing my Master's Thesis on *Subjective tagging of sounds* and I feel that I've been stuck with the same problem for quite a time now and need assistance to progress. I'll, in short, describe my goal and what I've accomplished so far.

I'm writing a program that lets users manually tag audio files **with a single label** according to their own, i.e. **subjective**, perception. The tags are always **adjectives**, like *happy*, *spooky* or *spacy*. The goal is to have the program automatically tag similar sounds with the correct label by finding related sounds using machine learning. The program currently looks like this:
[image: Current UI of the program]
Usage of the program goes like this:

1. The user adds sounds to be labeled.
2. The program analyses the files and searches for related sounds using *Algorithm 1*.
3. The user tags a sound and the program automatically tags related sounds using *Algorithm 2*.
4. The user can verify tags given by the program and choose to accept them or give the sound a new tag.
5. Repeat from step 1 or step 3.

---

By looking at the program flow above I've been able to implement step 1 using [AudioCommons Timbral Models](https://github.com/AudioCommons/timbral_models) to convert sounds to a usable data format, and step 2 with *Algorithm 1* using [Mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift) to find groups of related sounds. The idea is to use the groups found by *Algorithm 1* as a starting point when no tag has yet been given to a group. When one of the sounds in the group is tagged, all the sounds receive the same tag.

My problem, however, lies in step 3 with *Algorithm 2* and step 4. I've tried a few different approaches, but they all seem a bit off and not quite fit for the job.

My goal is to have the program **continuously or recursively** learn from user validation, hence improving over-usage. My thought process is to have a *verified* flag on each sound, which the user can use to say if a tag given to a sound by the program is correct or not. *Algorithm 2* should (re)learn from *verified* sounds in step 4 so that when step 3 is repeated, the automatic tagging of sounds done by the program is more accurate according to the user's choices.

**So my question is: What kind of algorithm(s) is suitable for step 3 and 4 in place of *Algorithm 2*?**

---

I've tried to make myself as clear as possible, but I'm quite new to machine learning, so feel free to point out confusing sections or errors.

In hope of assistance,

Andreas

---

Notes:

- I've used *tag* and *label* interchangeably throughout the text; they refer to the same thing.
- I want all machine learning to occur in isolation for a user, i.e. I **don't** want to learn from other user's input (like [Collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few observations from my side:

1. I think you should clarify your goal for yourself. Writing a program isn't a goal in itself. I'm missing the top level picture.
2. The second part: 'The goal is to have the program automatically tag similar sounds with the correct label by finding related sounds using machine learning.' is more like a goal, but where is the subjective part in it, and how does this answer questions in your thesis?
3. I'm not sure about the meaning of the output of Algorithm 1. Is this supervised or unsupervised classification? If it would be supervised, the 'supervision' is not subjective (until Algorithm 2). If is it unsupervised, the classes will find similarities, but the similarities are unlikely to correspond to the labels you intend to use.
4. However, if you take e.g. $k=9$ classes with k-means (you will have to optimize the number) the similarities in the classes will increase, and you could 'learn' the matching of labels and the classes. The $k$ classes should map to one of 3 labels.
5. Don't try to fit all these steps into one model. Create a few and connect them properly. Measure, interpret and report intermediate steps in your thesis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try to respond to your observations 

Comment: 1. I'm trying to create a solution that helps sound engineers categorise and organise their sounds by using subjective tags. My approach would be to create a program to minimise the manual effort needed to tag each sound individually. One  way to measure the efficiency would be to compare the number of interactions needed from a user to achieve a state of completeness, i.e. when all sounds have the correct tag according to the user. In my thesis I would have examples where the state of completeness is defined and compare the clicks needed to achieve this state vs. tagging each manually.

Comment: 2. By subjective I mean that I could tag say 10 sound examples as _happy_ and sad, where you could say that they are _spacy_, _chimy_ and _dissonant_. Each user could tag the same sounds with different labels and and with a varying number of labels, resulting in different amount of groups. This helps me answer the question of whether or not I can use e.g. Collaborative filtering in my program, which I can't in this case.

Comment: 3. Shoot, forgot to mention it! All data is unlabelled to start with, so Algorithm 1 is dealing with unlabelled data completely. The reason I'm trying to implement Algorithm 1 is to find naturally occurring groups of sound, which would be used to create a "shortcut" for Algorithm 2 so it would be have something to start with, thus generating the correct tag faster. I don't know if this is a valid approach; it was just something that seemed logical to me and that I've been trying out.

Comment: #2. Are your labels disjoint? E.g. Happy and Upbeat both allowed for the same sample?

Comment: #3, sounds like k-means for some k larger than the number of tags. Samples in the same class should sound very similar. This does not mean that sounds in different classes should sound dissimilar. Two or more different classes could both be labeled as 'Happy'. I would not attach a label to your k classes.

Comment: 4. The number of labels, _k_, is unknown at the start; we don't know how many labels a user will choose to use. It will also change with usage; if the user is say using only 2 labels currently, they could tag a sound with a new label, resulting in _k_ = 3. There is also a chance of _k_ decreasing, if the user chooses to join two labels, tagging one sound with an existing label.

Comment: 5. Yes, agree! I'm a bit lost though on what models I should choose and how to connect them 

Comment: 2. No, only one label per sample. It's a simplification, but makes the problem a bit more easy to grasp 

Comment: 3. Interesting point! I've been thinking a bit about this, and it seems resonable. This is pretty much how my current implementation of Algorithm 2 works. I use K-means and update _k_ whenever the user corrects a tag given by the program. The problems I've had is what happens if the user chooses to re-tag with an existing label, but I could, just like said, allow multiple groups to have the same label! 